Loading c/c++ dynamic libraries in python
Following is my development Environment;
Qt: 6.5.5,
pyside 6,
OS:  windows,
compiler for c++ libraries mscv2019

I am working on a project where the core logic is implemented in C/C++, and I am using QML for the UI. I am trying to create a sub-project where the business logic will be handled by Python, and the UI will still be in QML.
I want to load the C++ DLL into the Python code to allow communication between the two. 
The goal is for Python to act as the bridge between the UI (QML) and the C++ code.
As of now I have tried using these 2 methods to load the dll,
Method 1
dll_path = Path(r"C:\Simulator\Platform_Code\Build\QtCreator\outfiles\win64-x86-msvc\release\Test.dll")
if not dll_path.exists():
    print(f"DLL not found: {dll_path}")
    sys.exit(-1)

cpp_lib = QLibrary(str(dll_path))
print(f"Attempting to load cpp_lib from: {cpp_lib}")
result = cpp_lib.load()

if not result:
    print("Hi " + cpp_lib.errorString())
    sys.exit(-1)


if not cpp_lib.load():
    print(f"Failed to load the DLL: {cpp_lib.errorString()}")
    sys.exit(-1)
print("DLL loaded successfully.")

Method 2
def load_all_dlls(folder_path):
    for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
        if filename.endswith('.dll'):
            full_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
            try:
                ctypes.CDLL(full_path)
                print(f"Successfully loaded {full_path}")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Failed to load {full_path}: {e}")

dll_path = Path(r"C:\Simulator\Platform_Code\Build\QtCreator\outfiles\win64-x86-msvc\release\Test.dll")
if not dll_path.exists():
    print(f"DLL not found: {dll_path}")
    sys.exit(-1)

cpp_lib = QLibrary(str(dll_path))
print(f"Attempting to load cpp_lib from: {cpp_lib}")

but I am getting the error as :
Attempting to load cpp_lib from: \<PySide6.QtCore.QLibrary(0x140b6b0eb50) at 0x00000140B8C6F240\>
Hi Cannot load library C:\\Simulator\\Platform_Code\\Build\\QtCreator\\outfiles\\win64-x86-msvc\\release\\Test.dll: The specified module could not be found.


Run the dependency walker on your DLL - check what else it needs.  Make sure that whatever it needs is on %PATH% or in the local directory.

DLL not found usually happens for one of 2 reasons: or this dll cannot be really found on the path specified or (which is usually not obvious) one of its dependencies cannot be found.

Check the architecture of the dll matches that of python. If the python is 64bit, the dll must be also. Then investigate the dll with dependency walker.
